# Prevent URL parsing in IE for FTP

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ftp

The URL for my server is “ftptest.mydomain.com”

This server hosts FTP and HTTP.

If I type that address in the internet explorer 8 address bar without typing http:// or https:// it resolves to ftp://ftptest.mydomain.com.

Does anyone know a reg hack to prevent this behavior in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IE has some logic predicting the protocol, if it starts with ftp it defaults to ftp protocol. So I would say change the url to something that doesn't start with ftp.